# When triple count is very large, why is sparql federated query so slow, but local query so fast?

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, virtuoso, fuseki

I set up SPARQL endpoints on several linux servers (RDF database: fuseki 4.4.0, Number of triples: 6,000,000), and then queried several SPARQL endpoints through SPARQL Federated Query.

Results: sparql federated query is so slow, but local query so fast.

Sparql federated query (very slow: Several hours passed and there was no response):

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    {
        SERVICE SILENT <fuseki endpoint 1> {
            SELECT * WHERE {
                ?s ?p ?o .
            }
        }
    }
    UNION
    {
        SERVICE SILENT <fuseki endpoint 2> {
            SELECT * WHERE {
                ?s ?p ?o .
            }
        }
    }
} OFFSET 0 LIMIT 5
```

Local query (very fast, used 0.02 s):

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o .
} OFFSET 0 LIMIT 5
```

However, querying Virtuoso with the same sparql statement is very fast. Such as DBpedia, although there are hundreds of millions of triples.

Comment: what means "slow"? And which time do you expect? You're fetching 12million bindings over HTTP - this will take at least some time. How long does it take? the data is loaded into TDB backends? If so, local querying just 5 results is trivial, but for the SERVICE queries it obviously will fetch all results first, without any optimization it is just sending the query inside the `SERVICE` clause. If yo get lucky the `LIMIT` could be pushed to the `SERVICE`, but those optimizations are non-trivial - you always have to be SPARQL semantics conform in the end

Comment: by the way. latest Fuseki is 4.6.1 - don't stick to older versions if there is no obvious reason for

Comment: Thanks.

Very slow means: Several hours passed and there was no response.

Do you know how to push the `LIMIT` to the `SERVICE`?

Comment: I will try to test with Fuseki 4.6.1.

Comment: You could rewrite your query, and put a `LIMIT` into each SERVICE. Clearly, it depends on what you're doing with the data afterwards. In your current case it's trivial and totally valid to manually place a `LIMIT` into each `SERVICE` request.

Comment: "several hours" sounds way to long for only 6M triples -> how long does it take on each Fuseki to fetch all triples?

Comment: Thanks. `put a LIMIT into each SERVICE` is really the most effective way, and I would probably deal with this problem on demand.

Comment: I haven't tested `fetch all triples from Fuseki`. But It took me about six hours to execute by batch importing (10000 triples at a time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SERVICE` will return all results (a single HTTP request) for the `SERVICE` block. It does not know there is an overall query limit and a more complex query may be locally filtering of joining `SERVICE` results so they may need to be more than 5 returned.

Apache Jena 4.6.1 has new support for enhancing `SERVICE`: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/service_enhancer.html

Comment: Thanks. I will try to use Fuseki 4.6.1. By the way, Do you know how to upgrade Fuseki (4.4.0-4.6.1) without affecting TDB2 data (No configuration has been changed).

Comment: Switch the jars file over. No on-disk-data affected.

Comment: Thanks. After upgrading to Fuseki 4.6.1, `SERVICE` query is still slow (30s) when lots of triples are returned. But the same data is very fast in Virtuoso. I solved the problem temporarily by `put a LIMIT into each SERVICE`.

Comment: Jena reads all the results - it is defensive because of systems like Virtuoso that can abort and generate bad results (e.g. it sends 200 but timeouts or resource counts abort the execution mid way through). This in turn causes user confusion (often queries work some days and not other) and a support load on the Jena community. Line 201 in Service.java.